# How to set specific colors for specific values

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have a rather large set of data, composed of one array of tuples (coordinates) and one array of values associated with each coordinate. My problem is that those values are not just one integer but sometimes an array of possible values.

For example, I could have an array like this: [6,10,8,[4,5,6],4]. This corresponds to 5 coordinates.

I would like to plot this data using imshow. Basically I want to create my own colormap but I have only 11 different possible values, some of which being an array.

All the resources I've found only treat uniform values. Should I change my approach or is there a way to use this data as is?

I have tried using colors.boundaryNorms, but that obviously doesn't work for the sub-arrays.
As I am quite new to matplotlib I do not have much different ideas to try.

Comment: I suggest you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because, in the present form, I really have no idea what kind of plot you are looking for from such an array `[6,10,8,[4,5,6],4]`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reflection and considering I work with geospatial data, I switched to rasterio and Qgis to visualize my results.
Closing the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).